# How to release an NSMutableArray?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, nsmutablearray

I have an NSMutableArray with the following property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *alarmTableArray;

alarmTableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
FMDBDatabaseAccess *db = [[FMDBDatabaseAccess alloc] init];
alarmTableArray = [db getAlarm];
```

I tried releasing this array but I end up with EXC_BAD_ACCESS.
I am really worried about this.

How to release this array?

Comment: When do you release it ?

Comment: I tried releasing in ViewWillDisapper & at the end of a method which goes to other view

Comment: Maybe you need to use self.alarmTableArray to ensure you're accessing the property (and thus properly retaining the array)? Do you use @synthesize on the properties?

Comment: I tried that as well but when i do analyse it show memory leak in the object.. so only i removed the self..

Comment: Use `self.alarmTableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];` to assign values. It would be easier if you did `@synthesize alarmTableArray = _alarmTableArray;`and then use simply `_alarmTableArray = ...` thruout the module. Later in the dealloc method do `_alarmTableArray = nil;` and the release is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the descriptor of "strong" which is an ARC term. This should be retain and if you just set the property to nil it will release it automatically. You should set it to nil in your viewDidUnload since your ViewWillDissappear only means your viewcontroller is leaving visibility and not that it is being destroyed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I tried your answer but still there is the problem the memory is leaking over there..

Comment: Hmm, its hard to know for sure what the issue is but I would recommend just switching your entire project over to ARC with the XCode conversion tool. It will probably make your life easier and in this situation you would only have to maintain a reference to your array until you no longer need it.

Comment: No actually ARC is a precompile stage and it essentially puts all of the retain/release statements in your code behind the scenes. It should work with older versions and you are able to disable it on any files you want with a compile flag.

Comment: Is it if so how can i convert my project in to ARC.. any idea

Comment: updated my question please have a look at it..the leak showing in between the while loop

Answer (score 1):

### Updated Answer

I think I know what you're trying to do. You want grab an array of rows from your SQL and store it in one of your array.

One of the techniques for getting rows of data from SQL and storing into a class instance variable array is to NOT return a temporary array but pass the class instance variable array as a reference into your method and modify the array directly.

So instead of this pseudo-code

```
-(NSMutableArray *)doSomething
{
   NSMutableArray *tempArray;

   while (DB select statement has found rows)
   {
       CockTail *objCT = [[CockTail alloc] init];

       objCT.name = @"...";
       objCT.price = @"...";

       [tempArray addObject:objCT];

       [objCT release];
   }

   return [tempArray autorelease];
}

// class instance variable array
instanceVarArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
instanceVarArray = [self doSomething]; // here is where you confusion arise
```

You can do it this way:

```
-(void)doSomething:(NSMutableArray *)paramArray
{
    // remove previously fetched data
    [paramArray removeAllObjects];

    SQL select statement

    while(has rows)
    {
        CockTail *objCT = [[CockTail alloc] init];

        objCT.name = @"...";
        objCT.price = @"...";

        // NOTE: we are directly modifying our class instance variable array
        // here since it was passed by reference :D
        // and so there is no need to worry about releasing the array
        [paramArray addObject:objCT];

        [objCT release];
    }
}

// Now all you do is pass in your class instance variable array
instanceVarArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[self doSomething:instanceVarArray];
```

### Original Answer

Um, maybe I am wrong but aren't you essentially throwing away that "alloc init" on the first line here when you assign the array something from your FMDBDatabaseAccess:

```
// LINE 1: this instance of NSMutableArray here is allocated
alarmTableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

// LINE 2
FMDBDatabaseAccess *db = [[FMDBDatabaseAccess alloc] init];

// LINE 3:this line here essential breaks the pointer link point to the NSMutableArray instance on line 1 
alarmTableArray = [db getAlarm];
```

Now unless you do

```
// LINE 4
[alarmTableArray retain];
```

Otherwise, your alarmTableArray was never allocated (since you overwrote the pointer link). And as a result, you've caused a memory leak as your profiler told you.

Doing a release now would give your that EXEC_BAD_ACCESS

What I think you want to do is this:

```
alarmTableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
FMDBDatabaseAccess *db = [[FMDBDatabaseAccess alloc] init];

// this now uses the setter method (mutator method generated by @property) to do the copy
self.alarmTableArray = [db getAlarm];
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer..I will try yours and let you know +1 for clear explanation

Comment: I just edited my question with the image.. Could you have a look at that please

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your while loop, I have to ask why are you releasing a local scope variable?

```
 CockTail *cocktailValues = [[CockTail alloc] init];
 ...

 [cocktails addObject:cocktailValues];
 [cocktailValues release];
```

Breakdown of each line of code above:

1. When you alloc and init the CockTail object the release/retain count is 0.
2. Adding the object to the NSMutableArray increases the release/retain count to 1.
3. Releasing the CockTail object after you added it to array reduce the release/retain count back down to 0.

Therefore, later when you release the NSMutableArray or try to access an object in it, the objects are already gone.

Remember the number one rule, only release what you retain.

Comment: Thanks for your answer actually before i haven't released the local scope variable but while checking for memory leak in Analyse it points to that object.. So i released that local scope variable.. Now i couldn't release the NSMutuallArray because i found memory leak through Profiler where it points to the the Cocktail object values..